# Correct sentence structure and comma rule

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, commas

I would like to know if the following sentences are correct, i.e. do we need any commas here?- If you see a way to improve their structure, please let me know.

**I would like to gain insight into his work he did together with my sister on air pollution.**

Regarding this sentence, I was wondering whether there is a better word than "did" to describe a joint project work and is it correct to use no commas here?

**The study of air pollution conducted, among others, by my sister is innovative.**

Regarding this one, is the usage of the word among others correct here and do we need to put this phrase between two commas?

**So that upon taking a course on air pollution, I will be able to understand her work better.**

Regarding this one, is it okay to start a sentence like that or are there ways to express this in a nicer way (I have the felling that *so that* sounds a bit sloppy, but I don't know)

If you have any questions about this, please let me know.

Comment: I prefer *the work* over *his with*. Put *by my sister* first. Last one is not a complete sentence. Maybe drop *so that*? *Upon* still sounds a little stiff though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to gain insight into his work he **did** together with my sister on air pollution.

You can replace *did* with lots of other verbs (performed, accomplished, etc.) It depends on what they "did". I don't see any need for commas.

> The study of air pollution conducted, **among others**, by my sister is innovative.

Yes, phrases like this can be set off with commas. The sentence, without the phrase, is still a complete sentence.

> **So that** upon taking a course on air pollution, I will be able to understand her work better.

Using *so that* is OK if you want to connect the topic of this sentence to a previous one. But if this is a separate topic, leave it out. Comma use is OK.on